# Identifying data outliers

Tags: matlab

I have a data set organized into a structure. I have a large number of sensors, and each has four readings `a` through `d`, so the structure `D` contains `D.sensorID`, `D.a`, `D.b`, `D.c`, and `D.d`. I'm looking for the outliers in the distribution of the readings. I've plotted the data and chosen the limits and written a script that identifies sensorID's with readings outside of these limits and saves them to an array:

```
    aMax = 5;
    aHighIndices = find(D.a>aMax);
    aMin = 0;
    aLowIndices = find(D.a<aMin);
    aHighLength = size(aHighIndices);
    for i = 1:aHighLength
    A_hi(i) = D.sensorID(aHighIndices(i));
    end
```

This is repeated: `a_Hi`, `a_Low`, `b_Hi`, etc... and then I patch the results together:

`outliers = [A_hi; A_low; B_low; B_hi; C_low; C_hi; D_low; D_hi];`

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Your methodology looks fine. If you're looking for other ways to find outliers, then here is another method: Think about a 2D Gaussian centered on the mean readings for each sensor. When a particular sensor reading goes two standard deviations, then perhaps you might count it as an outlier. Now instead of having to set an hi/low threshold around each sensor, you just need to fits normals to each sensor, and define one threshold- that is, how many standard deviations away from the mean a point has to be before it is considered an outlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**
You iterate through each array (*i.e.* vector) of readings two times with `find`:
once for finding the high outliers and once for finding low outliers. You can do it in one iteration simply by:

```
a_outlier_indices = find(D.a < aMin | D.a > aMax);
```

**2.**
Another thing: generally speaking `for` in MATLAB is rather expensive, try using the built-in abilities of the MATLAB syntax to produce the same results. More specifically, MATLAB allows you to extract a sub-vector out of another vector using a vector of indices:

```
a_outliers = D.sensorID(a_outlier_indices);
```

Simply feeding `D.a` with a vector of indices yields the desired vector of outliers.

**3.**
Also, an advice for good practice: consider storing arrays `a` through `d` in a cell array of vectors instead of separate arrays, something like: `D.readings = {a, b, c, d}`, and defining corresponding thresholds cell array (`thr` in my example), so you can save some code by using a loop:

```
thr = {[aMin, aMax]; [bMin, bMax]; [cMin, cMax]; [dMin, dMax]}
outliers = cell(4, 1);
for i = 1:4
   outlier_indices = find(D.readings{i} < thr{i}(1) | D.readings{i} > thr{i}(2));
   outliers{i} = D.sensorID(outlier_indices);
end
```

Now you'll have everything in the cell array `outliers`. To access the *a* outliers use `outliers{1}`, to access the *b* outliers use `outliers{2}`, and so on...

You can of course patch everything together (like in the question) into one vector by simple concatenation inside the `for` loop:

`outliers = [outliers, D.sensorID(outlier_indices)];`

instead of the `outliers{i} = ...` statement.

P.S

I'm assuming that using min/max thresholds is what you want to use when finding outliers.
There are other methods to find outliers, but those will yield different results.